# (Flutter SqlServerSocket) How to install DartClient

Tags: sql-server, flutter

I want to use SqlServerSocket to query a Microsoft Sql Server database. I managed to install the SqlServerSocket, but it also asks me to install the DartClient package. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: When the tools to achieve a task in a given language are difficult to use (or basically non-existent) it's time to step back and take a fresh look at things. Dart is a language for web and mobile apps, so why do you want to connect apps directly to a DB server? Why don't you want to follow accepted patterns of connecting client apps to an API (e.g.: RESTful web services) and then the API to your preferred DB solution? Isolating the clients from the DB architecture means you can completely change the DB environment (scale up, scale out, or change providers) without affecting the clients at all.